# I am Nigerian and I need to travel from India to US

Tags: visas, usa

I am Nigerian and my home is in Nigeria. I am living in India on a working Visa, which is about to expire.

My question is can I get a visa to visit the United States from India or do I need to go back to Nigeria and obtain a visa to the US from there?

Comment: You can apply, but you will probably be refused unless you can demonstrate that you are going to be working somewhere else after your work in India ends.

Comment: Third world citizenship + no ties to where you are living = basically zero chance of a US visa.  Don't waste your money.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you may want to [first check the wait times for interviews](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-niv-waittimeinfo.asp), to ensure that your current visa does not expire before the process is complete.

> [Q.7 If I am a third-country national living in the India, can I apply for a nonimmigrant visa](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-gen-faq.asp) in New Delhi, Mumbai, Chennai, Hyderabad or Kolkata?
>
> Applicants are generally advised to apply in their country of nationality or residence. Any person who is legally present in India may apply for a visa in [New Delhi, Mumbai, Chennai, Hyderabad or Kolkata](https://www.usembassy.gov/india/). However, applicants should decide where to apply based on more than just convenience or delay in getting an appointment in their home district. One thing to consider, for example, is in which consular district the applicant can demonstrate the strongest ties.
>
> There is no guarantee that a visa will be issued, nor is there a guarantee of processing time. If refused, there is no refund of the application fee.